# How to form cloud formation template without cdk synt and cdk deploy in AWS-CDK app?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

So my question is in AWS-CDK can we form cloud formation template in a programatic way? without using cdk synth and cdk deploy commands. If there is a option to run in programatic way then why this app.synth() is nor working??

I am expecting without cdk synth and cdk deploy cloud formation template has to be formed when we run app.py , because we have app.synth line in program.
if that app.synth is not working is there any other way to form cloudformation template??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking: the CDK doesn't provide a clean API for programmatic usage, there is a huge GitHub issue that revolves around the topic: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk-rfcs/issues/300

In TypeScript, there are some ways to work around the issues and use it in a programmatic fashion: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/18667#issuecomment-1075348390 - maybe this can at least give you a starting point for python.